# How to add background hover color on bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a background colour to the links when I hover over them
and change the colour of the social media icons when I also hover them.

I have looked and tried a lot of answers that I've searched for, but still it doesn't work for me when I try.

Can someone please help? Many thanks

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="LOGO.png" class="img-responsive logo"></a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Featured</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Brand new</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a class="navbar-text" href="#">
      <img src="insta.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-text" href="#">
      <img src="Twitter.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-text" href="#">
      <img src="facebook.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `:hover` selector to change the `background-color` property of  menu items that are on hover like this:

```
.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.navbar-text:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the above code:

```css
.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="//picsum.photos/50/50" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Featured</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Brand new</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a class="navbar-text" href="#">
      <img src="insta.png" width="30"height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-text" href="#">
      <img src="Twitter.png" width="30"height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-text" href="#">
      <img src="facebook.png" width="30"height="30" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was totally getting the hover section wrong. All new to this - appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:hover`

```css
.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #B10331;
}
.navbar-text:hover {
  background-color: #B10331;
}
```